# How can one get the indices of duplicate elements in a list of OrderedDicts?

Tags: set, ordereddictionary

I have a list of `OrderedDicts` and I want to get the indices in that list of the elements that are duplicates. Conceptually, it is a bit like the following example, which features a list of `int`s:

```
>>> def indices_of_list_element_duplicates(x):
...     seen = set()
...     for index, element in enumerate(x):
...         if isinstance(element, list):
...             element = tuple(element)
...         if element not in seen:
...             seen.add(element)
...         else:
...             yield index
... 
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 9, 1]
>>> indices = [index for index in indices_of_list_element_duplicates(a)]
>>> indices
[6, 7, 9]
```

How can the equivalent of this be done for a list of `OrderedDicts`? When I try to this function on the `OrderedDicts`, I encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# ...
if isinstance(element, OrderedDict):  # checking for type dict would be enough
    element = tuple(element.items())
# ...
```

This converts the dictionary to a tuple of tuples which can, in turn, be an element of your set. Before, you were trying to add an object to the `set` which does not implement hashing.

Be aware that the given dictionaries have to be recursively restricted to hashable value types. Otherwise you will experience a similar issue.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(a=[1,2,3])
set().add(tuple(d.items()))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Ah that is very helpful. Thanks for the tip about checking recursively for unhashable value types.